# Access server.servlet.context-path from @Configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm new to spring-boot and I'm setting up a new server.
My company separate configurations in different files (e.g.: jdbc.properties, smtp.properties, etc etc..). All configurations are put in the folder *"property-files"* into Tomcat folder (as sibling of "webapps" folder) and into specialized folder with name of given applicaion; for example if my application is called:"wonderful-server" all my configuration files will be in:*"@TomcatFolder/property-files/wonderful-server/"*.

My idea is to access property files with absolute file path, like this: "file:${catalina.home}/property-files#{server.servlet.context-path}/smtp.properties".
But if I try to access "server.servlet.context-path" from a @Configuration class I obtain null.

---

I've tried to put into application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/wonderful-server
```

and add to my @Configuration class:

```
@Value("${server.servlet.context-path=/wonderful-server}") String contextPath;
```

but when spring bootup, contextPath contain null. The same if I use # instead of $.

---

Then I've tried to put into the main of my @SpringBootApplication class:

```
System.setProperty("server.servlet.context-path", "/formx-server");
```

and use in my @Configuration class:

```
String contextPath = System.getProperty("server.servlet.context-path");
```

but when spring bootup, contextPath contain null. The same if I use:

```
@Value("#{systemProperties['server.servlet.context-path']}") private String contextPath;
```

or:

```
@Value("#{server.servlet.context-path}") private String contextPath;
```

---

My @configuration classes are really simple, for example:

```
@Configuration
public class EmailConfig {

    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender getJavaMailSender() {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

        try {
            Properties props = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties( new FileSystemResource(System.getProperty("catalina.home")+"/property-files/wonderful-server/smtp.properties"));
            mailSender.setHost(props.getProperty("mail.host"));
            mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(props.getProperty("mail.port")));

            mailSender.setUsername(props.getProperty("mail.username"));
            mailSender.setPassword(props.getProperty("mail.password"));

            Properties properties = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
            properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", props.getProperty("mail.transport.protocol"));
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", props.getProperty("mail.smtp.auth"));
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", props.getProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable"));
            properties.put("mail.debug", props.getProperty("mail.debug"));

        } catch (IOException e) {
           // e.printStackTrace();
            LOG.error("Error to send email: "+e.getMessage());
        }


        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

In this class I've used an absolute path with static context-path, I'm trying to use it instead as variable.

---

In advance: thank you everyone for your precious time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `=`instead of `:`

Inside Properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/wonderful-server
```

But inside Configuration:

Default Value follows after `:`:

```
@Value("${server.servlet.context-path:/wonderful-server}") String contextPath;
```